# Webgl drawelements rotating square

Tags: javascript, webgl

Ok, I've been banging my head for enough in the attempt of making a square rotate with drawElements.
The code works fine with drawarrays and works fine if the square is still and I use drawElement call.
Now in this fiddle, I'm trying to make it rotate, (using drawElements) but I can't see anything. I've set up the square buffer and the indices. I've debugged, and the data looks correct, so I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Here is the fiddle.

```
var vertices = [-1,-1,-2, //FRONT FACE
                 1,-1,-2,
                 1,1,-2,
                -1,1,-2];
var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW); 

vertexBuffer.itemSize = 3;
vertexBuffer.numItems = parseInt(vertices.length/vertexBuffer.itemSize);

var indices = [0,1,2,0,2,3]; 

var cubeBufferIndex = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeBufferIndex);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3joez/mpj3dts7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the [depthFunc to EQUAL](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glDepthFunc.xml) in combination with clearing the depth buffer to `1.0` only draws fragments that have a depth of exactly 1.0. See the linked resource for more information on depth functions. Just remove the two lines below and everything renders fine.

```
gl.depthFunc(gl.EQUAL);
gl.clearDepth(1.0);
```